# Zero-dimensional Scheme is globally generated

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be zero-dimensional scheme over a field $k$. How can I conclude that $X$ is in this case globally generated?

My ideas: Let $x \in X$ arbitrary. I wan't to show that there exist a global section $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ such that $s(x) \neq 0$  in the stalk of $x$. By definition the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X, x}$ isn't zero, right? So I can take a non zero $r_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. The idea is to lift $r_x$ to global section. What does tell me that $X$ is zero-dimensional in topological sense? Does it refer to Krull dimension? Is it clear that then $X$ schould be discrete? If not, how to see ist?

Comment: What do you mean by 'a scheme is globally generated'?

Comment: The global section of the structure always contain $1$ and the structure sheaf of any scheme is thus globally generated.